# When using listchars, I can only get 2-space hardtabs

Tags: vim, unicode

I'm using the following [.vimrc](https://github.com/sethbuzz/dotfiles/blob/dot/.vimrc). Which contains (but not limited to) the following:

```
set encoding=utf-8
set tabstop=4
set autoindent
set list lcs=tab:·\ ,trail:•,eol:¬
```

This should give me four-space hard tabs, with the first character being displayed as a small mid-line dot, and the remaining three characters as spaces.  But what I get is two-space hard tabs.  Something else in my vimrc is throwing off the tab spacing.

Clearly I'm doing something wrong, and giving myself two-space hard tabs.  I've researched listchars, vim compile flags and trying to input non-breaking space into my vimrc. Any other ideas what I'm doing wrong??

Comment: I have the following picture after applying your settings: [link](http://i44.tinypic.com/2n8zssw.png). It seems for me that this is what you asked for. Am I wrong?

Comment: Then it must be something else in my .vimrc file :-(. I will amend my question to reflect this.

Comment: I believe that the problem is lines 102-106 of your .vimrc file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just looked at your `_vimrc`; the confusion is in the following lines

```
augroup htmldjango
   set tabstop=2
   set softtabstop=2
   set shiftwidth=2
augroup END
```

You're using `set` command and rewriting your previous `tabstop`, `softtabstop` and `shiftwidth` settings *regardless of filetype*. Therefore, you're effectively setting your tab to 2.

It would be better maybe (and my guess is this is what you were trying to do) were you to use

```
augroup htmldjango
   autocmd!
   autocmd FileType html setlocal tabstop=2
   autocmd FileType html setlocal softtabstop=2
   autocmd FileType html setlocal shiftwidth=2
augroup END
```

therefore setting different `tabstop`, `softtabstop`, etc. *only when HTML filetype is used*.

Notice: I have no idea what is a htmldjango filetype so you might want to modify that part for what suits you best.

Comment: This is great. Silly me. I should have suspected that was where the error was coming from.  That block almost never worked for me either.

Comment: @SethBuzz You should use `setlocal` for filetype-specific stuff. New code is overwriting this settings *for all buffers with any filetype* that will be opened after any html file.